# Control data come from sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, controls

I have a dropdownlist and it takes names of neighborhood from sql.
I want to show neighborhood's features on screen.
If I choose a neighborhood has been processed before now, It's no problem. My code can show features of its neighborhood.
But if I choose a new neighborhood (nobody adds information about that neighborhood before). There are no different thing on the screen.
I want to show on dropdownlist "New" as text. I defined 'else' status in my code.
How can I solve this problem?
That is my code :

```
        string DurumTespiti = "";
        string mahalle = ""; //mahalle means “neighborhood”
        ddlMahalle.Visible = true; // it is a dropdownlist
                    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source = WEBPMT\\ARCSQL;UID=sa;PWD=PMT*1881;DATABASE=ProjeTakip;");
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
        baglanti.Open();
        komut.Connection = baglanti;
        komut.CommandText = "select * from ProjeTablo";
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            mahalle = "";

            mahalle = dr["mahalle"].ToString();              

            if (mahalle == ddlMahalle.SelectedValue) // Compare value of dropdownlist and name of neighborhood in sql.
            {
                Label9.Text = "Mahalle doğru seçildi!";
                }

                mahalle = "";

            } 
            else
            { // if value of dropdown list couldn’t be find in sql                                
                Label9.Text = "Böyle bir mahalle yok";
            }
            mahalle = "";
        }          
        dr.Close();           
        baglanti.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your code, sample data, and expected results.